# magento dropdown on frontend can't be selected

Tags: magento

I suddenly realised that my Magento select boxes on the frontend can't be selected. When I click on the specific option it freezes like there's something preventing the default action of selecting the option and the options remain expanded. I have no ideas what to do. Tried to inspect it with Firebug and see if there are any errors but it shows none. very very nasty issue and can't find any answer googling about it - magento 1.9.1 is my version.

Answer (score 0):

THe problem was only in Firefox and not in other browsers so hopefully it will be resolved in next version.

Comment: this does not look like plain magento+firefox issue. I believe, you have made some modifications to theme (css specifically).